# package-install doesn't pick up dependencies that are already in site-lisp

Tags: package, load-path

I have a bunch of software git-cloned into my `site-lisp/` directory. It and all of its sub-directories are in my `load-path`. The problem I noticed is that `package-install` sometimes insists on pulling dependencies into `elpa/` even when such packages already exist in `site-lisp/`. To be more specific:

`package-install helm-descbinds` insists on installing Helm 1.5 even though not only do I have the latest helm in in my `load-path` from `site-lisp/helm/` but by the time the install gets called, `(require 'helm-config)` will have happened.

Who's at fault here? Is it the `helm-descbinds` package itself and I should be raising an issue with its maintainers? Or is there some obvious knob I need to turn in packages so the existing functionality gets picked up? Basically I just want to be sure that stuff in `site-lisp/` gets precedence. This very well maybe the case already, but then why install stuff that's already available?

Comment: What did you expect?  You bypass package.el, and wonder that it doesn't magically know about what you installed manually?

Comment: I guess I expect it to at least check my `features` list and see **helm** already there? Maybe I'm overthinking it.

Comment: Packages are not the same as features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's alright if `package` installs a different `helm` version.
The important part is which version gets `require`'d first.
So if you put your `(require 'helm-config)` earlier than `package` does,
you're fine.
Just to make sure that you have to correct one:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "git-helm-path")
(require 'helm-config)
```

### edit:

It seems from your comments is that your issue is with `PATH`
priorities. `load-path` is just like `PATH` in Unix: the first file on
the list that provides `helm` will be loaded when you require `helm`.

It's fine to have multiple versions of `helm` on the path, as long as
you know what you're doing. If you want a relaxed approach, just
delete your git stuff and leave everything to the package manager.
Otherwise, you'll have to work for it and make sure that your
`load-path` is properly set up. There's no magic pill, otherwise we'd
have it in Unix.

Comment: I would've thought that all package-install does is download, then add directory to the **load-path**. Having to `(require 'helm-config)` before installing anything else seems really dissatisfying if only for the fact that Emacs doesn't make a good use of information that it already has. Having added everything in my **site-lisp/** to **load-path** I then bulk-install packages with package-install and then config them. Question is which features get picked up? `features` list shows helm and friends there, but which files are being used site-lisp or elpa? Am I not thinking straight?

Comment: @zeRusski You confuse features and packages.  These are orthogonal concepts.  Compare [Named Features](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html#Named-Features) and [Packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Packaging-Basics.html#Packaging-Basics).

Comment: @lunaryorn right, tu for pointers. `symbol-file` and `load-history` do confirm that the elpa version gets loaded. Oh, fancy `list-load-path-shadows` actually shows what's shadowed.

Comment: @zeRusski Add your site-lisp directory to `load-path`  "after* calling `package-initialize`.  That should make sure that your manually installed version gets loaded.  But ideally, pick one way and only one way of installing stuff.  Everything else is asking for trouble.

Comment: @abo-abo unless I'm very much mistaken your solution will only work if "git-helm-path" (that is my **site-lisp/** subdirs) appears earlier in **load-path** than packages in elpa? Which means I need to juggle the **load-path** before stuff gets required

Comment: You can either 1: load before package-init, 2: load after package-init, 3: add path after package-init and not load.
The only bad option is to add path before package-init and not load.

Comment: @lunaryorn I think your suggestion is right on target. Thanks