# Manually installed pdf-tools breaks package handling because it is not recognized as a dependency

Tags: package, use-package, pdf-tools

The **situation** is:

I install `pdf-tools` manually and load it with the following snippet:

```lisp
(use-package pdf-tools
   :pin manual
   :load-path "my/load/path/to/the/git/repo/lisp"
   :config
    ....stuff...)
```

Everything works fine, and I am happy with this setup. But....

The **problem** is:

I cannot install any package which *depends* on `pdf-tools`, since the package manager does not recognize it as being installed. Thus, `M-x package-list-packages` lists me quite a bunch of packages which are "incompatible" because they depend on `pdf-tools`. But it is there!

How can I convince the package manager to install these packages?

EDIT:

I've tried the answer given [to this very similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38020/tell-package-el-that-dependency-is-already-taken-care-of?rq=1) and added `pdf-tools` to `package--builtin-versions`. Still not available for the package manager, the other package depending on it is still blocked.

Comment: If the package manager doesn't recognise it as being installed then (at least by default) it would install it as a dependency.

Comment: E.g. If I tell the package manager to install `pdf-view-restore` and `pdf-tools` isn't already installed, then they will *both* be installed.

Comment: I think "incompatible" would *more likely* indicate that the package manager *does* recognise that `pdf-tools` is installed, and that the other packages depend upon a *newer* version of it.

Comment: I see. The reasoning seems to be right, but I cannot verify that the versions are the problem. `pdf-tools` are version 1.0, the requirement for the 'incompatible' packages is > 0.8 or 0.7, depending on the package. So versions do not seem to be the problem. My problem is: How do I tell the package manager to consider pdf-tools & friends as installed? It seems that I should hack `package-alist`, but I am not really willing to do it.